# Matlab faster rcnn multiple classes and atributes

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I've been trying to train my neural network to preform object detection.

My dataset consists of 3 classes. Each has its own attributes.

I don't know how to feed my dataset to the net and would love some assistance.

```
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\18.jpeg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x4 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\19.jpeg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x4 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\22.jpeg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x4 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\24.jpeg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x4 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\25.jpeg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x4 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\105.jpg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x1 struct
'C:\Users\pawel\Documents\MATLAB\Datasetfinal\423.jpg'  1x0 struct  1x0 struct  1x1 struct
```